# Save date to Shared Preferences

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I want to save the current date to a textview within my listview I have everything else setup so no need for help there just saving date to textview my code is as follows can someone tell me what wrong?

```
SharedPreferences settings =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putLong("time", date.getTime());
                editor.commit();
                Date date2 = new Date(settings.getLong("time", 0));
```

Comment: what errors are you getting

Comment: @tyczj none its just not saving the date instead tomorrow it will set all dates in my listview to the tomorrows date sounds like the getView and .setText i know

Comment: Your code looks okay to me. Have you debugged that part you posted. I'm pretty sure it works fine. Maybe the problem (dates in ListView?) lays somewhere else?

Answer (score 4):

Most of the methods of Date class is deprecated. You should use the Calendar class.
`Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();`

To store in your SharedPreferences, I suggest you to store a long, wich is return by `c.getTimeInMillis();`

To get this date and store in a Calendar object, you should put `c.setTimeInMillis(myTimeStoredInSharedPreferences)`

Answer (score 1):

I'd say forget both about Date and Calendar - use just:

```
SharedPreferences settings =
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
settings.edit().putLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).commit();
// get the time and make a date out of it
Date date2 = new Date(settings.getLong("time", 0));
```

That is use `currentTimeMillis()` internally in your app and just use Date if you want to display something to the user

Never use `Calendar.getInstance()` locally - it is expensive

If you use dates all the time consider JodaTime

Comment: do i place the Date date2 = new Date(settings.getLong("time", 0)); in the onCreate of the activity??

Comment: @LimpLimp: you place it where you need it - that is for _getting_ the time from SP and making a date from it - edited the post